# simple ways to check email validation and multiple emails?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I've scoured this site and the internet for a good simple solution on how to check if an email is being entered twice to my database and if it's a valid email. I have not been able to find a simple solution. Here is my form and php. thanks in advance

```
    <div class="email-survey">  
                <?php if(isset($success)) { ?>
                    <div class="success_survey">Thanks you! Your survey has been submitted</div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(isset($error)) { ?>
                    <div class="error_survey">
                <?php echo $error; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

        <form name="settings" action="/survey-confirm.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
   </div>

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/system/init.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(empty($_POST['email'])) { 

            $error = "Please enter a valid email";

        }else{
            $success = true;    

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO survey_email 
                (email) VALUES('".$_POST['email']."' ) ") 
                or die(mysql_error()); 
            header('Location: /survey-email-confirm.php');
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Don't scour for "duplicate emails in database". Look for "detect if some data exists in the database already". e.g. DO a select query and filter by that email address. If you get record(s) back, then it obviously exists in the DB.

Comment: I agree with Mark B on the duplication part, as for validation there's two roads. Regular Expressions (http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) or PHP filters (http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a link to the user. When they click it use `$_GET` information to validate that it's a valid email. Of course you should use a MySQL `SELECT` query to test to see if the email exists to prevent duplicate entries. The following shows the `mysqli` Object Oriented approach, which I recommend to save you from retyping stuff:

```
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $em = trim($_POST['email']);
  if($em === '' || !preg_match('/^.{1,62}@.{1,62}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $em)){
    $error = 'Please Enter a Valid Email';
  }
  else{
    $sml = $db->query("SELECT email FROM survey_mail WHERE email='$em'");
    if($sml->num_rows > 0){
      $error = 'Sorry, this Email is Already in Use';
    }
    else{
      $eml = $db->real_escape_string($em);
      $db->query("INSERT survey_email (email) VALUES ('$eml')");
      //the below leaves out the $doctype, beginning html tag and your $css
      $dt = date('l, F j, Y, g:i:sa T', time());
      $msg = "$doctype<title>Your Email Was Received</title><style type='text/css'>$css</style></head><body><a href='http://www.domain/wherever.php?em=someCrazyHashOrSomthing'>Please Click the Following Link to Confirm Your Email Address is Valid</a></div><div><b>Sent:</b> $dt <br /><b>Email:</b> $em <br /></div></body></html>";
      mail($em, 'Thank You for Contacting Us', $msg, "From: name@domain.com\r\ncontent-type: text/html");
    }
  }
  $sml->free(); $db->close();
}
else{
  $em = 'example@example.com';
}
```

Of course, now you need the PHP to validate the link information in the email. I'm not going to do all your work for you, so have fun. You may consider the use of my Library [PHPglue](https://www.PHPglue.com). It will do multiple checks on data, with very little work, and includes automatic JavaScript errors, without needing to know JavaScript.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is for non-session usage

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/system/init.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // get the email address
    $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));

    // see if email is empty or invalid
    if($email == '' || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error_message = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    } else {
        // email is valid
        $success = true;    

        // check if email address is already in database
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $check = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

        if($check > 0) {
            // email address exists
            $error_message = 'That email address exists';
        } else {
            // email address does not exist
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO survey_email (email) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."' ) ") or die(mysql_error()); 
            header('Location: /survey-email-confirm.php');
        }
    }
}
```

You should use mysqli or PDO, as mysql is depreciated. Also, NEVER put data into your database without sanitizing it first - even if your PHP script created it. Never trust data, especially from user input.

Edit: I misread the OP's question. Updated with new answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is for non-session usage

Comment: You don't need a session for this.

Comment: I see totally different answers to mine. Did I misunderstand your question? Do you want to verify a user after they sign up? or make sure an email address is a real/valid email address?

Comment: see updated answer. I *think* this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I will describe the steps you should make to have a nice solution:

1. In the Data Access Layer of your PHP you should run a query which checks whether there is any email address in the database which is congruent with this email. Something like this should be run on the database server (beware of SQL injections, though):

   SELECT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM users WHERE email = 'test@example.com')
2. If the email exists show the error
3. Implement a PHP function which will test the email address to be valid or not using regular expressions. Use google to find a nice regexp.
4. If the format of the email is not valid, show an error
5. Implement an email format validator in Javascript (optional, but it is better to not send the request at all if the email address is invalid) using the same regexp you used at your PHP function.
6. Implement the Submit event of your form to only submit if the email address passed Javascript validation.

So, when the client uses the form you first check the email address with the Javascript validator and only send the request if it is valid, in PHP check for the email format and if valid check whether it is duplicate in the database. Handle the possible failures and the success scenario. Happy debugging.